# Jquery - each and data()

Tags: jquery

how can i get all "rt_XX" with jquery each?
I have no idea :/ .. Hope somebody can help me.

```
$("body").data('conf_pkc', 'normal');
$("body").data('conf_sst', '0');
$("body").data("rt_01", { tw:'k25', title:'Bernd', descr:'man' });
$("body").data("rt_12", { tw:'k115', title:'Hugo', descr:'man' });
$("body").data("rt_55", { tw:'k25', title:'Jan', descr:'man' });

/*    
    $.each( XXXXXXXXXXXX , function(k, v){

        var rt_tw = $('body').data('rt_01').tw;
        var rt_tw = $('body').data('rt_01').tw;        

        $('#d1').append('rt_tw  -> '+rt_tw+'<br />');
        $('#d1').append('rt_title  -> '+title+'<br />');        
        $('#d1').append('rt_descr  -> '+descr+'<br />');

    });

*/
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/543/

Thanks in advance.
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.4+, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var data = $("body").data();

for (p in data) {
   if (p.substring(0,3) == "rt_") {
      var x = data[p];
      alert(x.tw);
      alert(x.title);
      alert(x.descr);
   }
}
```

Just tested this at your link.  Works as intended!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since there's only one `<body>` there's absolutely no need to be binding data to it (unless data is being utilised by some 3rd-party widget/plugin).

All data can be kept in some global configuration object or even global vars -- either will be better than the overhead of `$('body').data('foo')`.

How about:

```
var rt = []; // An array

rt[12] = {...};
rt[55] = {...};
```

Note: you may want to use an object (`{}`) instead of an array -- an object would be more friendly with a sparse array of values when looping.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").data('conf_pkc', 'normal');
$("body").data('conf_sst', '0');
$("body").data("rt_01", { tw:'k25', title:'Bernd', descr:'man' });
$("body").data("rt_12", { tw:'k115', title:'Hugo', descr:'man' });
$("body").data("rt_55", { tw:'k25', title:'Jan', descr:'man' });


var b    =  $('body');
var data = b.data();
var arey = [];

for(var i in data) {
   if(i.match(/rt_?\d{2}/) ) {
        arey.push(i);
    }
}

$.each(arey, function( index, val ) {
   var item = $('body').data( val )
    for(var i in item ) {
      (function(t) {
        console.log(val + ' => '+ t+ ' : ' +item[t]);
      })(i);
    }
});
```

Code tested on firebug,  Works fine =)

**Demo** : **http://jsbin.com/ufoza3**

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
value = jQuery.data($("body").find("xxx")[0], "rtxx)");
```

You'll need to loop through the elements if you don't use [0]. This is just to get you going.